# How to stop database from duplicating items

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im learning Nodejs and MongoDB, and I succesfully connected to database and saving to database is working, but if for exemple i add another item to the list,  and run the script again to save to the database it duplicates the ones that already exists.
I want to whenever I need to add a new item do the project, it only adds that specific item instead of adding everything again.

This is my seeder:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Keys = require("../config/auth");

mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);
mongoose.set("useNewUrlParser", true);
mongoose.connect(Keys.MongoURI);

const products = [
  new Product({
    imagePath:
      "test",
    title: "test1",
    description: "test1",
    price: 20
  }),
  new Product({
    imagePath:
      "test2",
    title: "test2",
    description: "test2",
    price: 20
  })
];

let done = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].save(function(err, result) {
    done++;
    if (done === products.length) {
      exit();
    }
  });
}
function exit() {
  mongoose.disconnect();
}
console.log(products);
```

so if for example i add a new product here, it should check the database if like: title match on database then dont add to database, only the ones that the title are available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent having multiple product with the same title by creating a unique index in your collection.

```js
yourProductSchema.index({ "title": 1 }, { unique: true });
```

This will generate an `err` when inserting document with existing title.

More info: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Another way, if you want other fields to be updated also. You can use upsert. More info here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 0):

To create a unique index, use the db.collection.createIndex() method with the unique option set to true.

For example, to create a unique index on the title field of the products collection, use the following operation in the mongo shell:

```
db.products.createIndex( { "title": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```